# Using data from an aysnc Javascript http request? (aws serverless)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm using the nodejs serverless module to create a lambda aws function.

```
'use strict';
const request = require('request');
const options = {
  url: 'https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v2.0/pull/nfl/2018-regular/games.json',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from("1da103" 
+ ":" + "MYSPORTSFEEDS").toString('base64')
  }
}

//this is automatically called by aws
module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
  let result;
  request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    result = JSON.parse(body).lastUpdatedOn; //never happens cuz of async
  });
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      input: result,
    }),
  };
};
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't return output from the get request, because the assignment to the result variable (in the async get request) happens after the return statement. I don't think I can turn the outer function into a callback function for the get request. How could I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative could be to extract the request logic and put it into a new function.

*Remember, you need to catch any errors, so use a `try-catch` block for doing that.*

```
'use strict';
const request = require('request');
const options = {
    url: 'https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v2.0/pull/nfl/2018-regular/games.json',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Buffer.from("1da103"
            + ":" + "MYSPORTSFEEDS").toString('base64')
    }
};

function getResult() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            resolve(JSON.parse(body).lastUpdatedOn); //never happens cuz of async
        });
    });
}

//this is automatically called by aws
module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
    let result = await getResult();
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
            input: result,
        }),
    };
};
```